Guides and best practices for journal design
There's no shortage of resources on book design, both tool-agnostic and TeX-specific.  Some fairly comprehensive ones I have relied on in the past include A Few Notes on Book Design by Peter Wilson, Book Design by Andrew Haslan, and "Book design for TeX users" (Part 1 and Part 2) by Philip Taylor.  I also recall with appreciation the more focused contributions I've encountered in TUGboat, such as Pablo Rossell-González's article on reproducing classic book layouts and Claudio Beccari and Andrea Guadagni's case study on the design of a reference book.
Are there similar resources (preferably but not necessarily ones that are specific to the TeX ecosystem) that speak specifically to the design of scholarly journals?  I understand that much of the advice for books also applies to journals, though some of it clearly does not, and for all I know journals may present unique design challenges of their own (quite apart from the downstream production issues).  I would be very interested in reading a long-form, comprehensive guide along the lines of the ones for books I've cited above, but failing this, pointers to shorter pieces covering case studies or individual aspects of the design process would be welcome.
Note that I'm not asking about technical production issues relating to the combination of individual submissions into a single document, the extraction of article metadata, or the use of end-to-end publishing software (for accepting article submissions, assigning them to reviewers, and publishing them on the web).  These are all very important issues but discussing them here would make this question too broad.  (I've got a separate question in the works for that topic, referencing the TeX-specific production resources I've found so far.)  What I am interested in for the present is what design aspects relating to the page layout, the choice of typeface, how individual articles or the issue as a whole should be structured, etc. require special consideration for journals as opposed to books.
Here are some TUGboat and TeXniques articles I am already aware of, but these are just isolated case studies rather than comprehensive overviews, and many of them say more about the production process than the decisions concerning the design and its implementation in TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt.

"How to create a TeX journal: A personal journey" by Barbara Beeton
"Ten years of work in Wiadomości Matematyczne — an adventure with
LaTeX and Emacs hacking by Marcin Borkowski
"The 16 faces of a Dutch math journal" by Hans Hagen
"TeX, linguistics, and journal production" by Christina Thiele

I'm also particularly enamoured with Newsletters from the Desktop by Joe Grossmann (Ventana Press, 1994).  Despite its age, I found it to be a great introduction to the typographic elements and terminology specific to periodical publications, and while it's not tied to any particular software, its design advice is geared toward flashy newsletters and magazines rather than academic journals.
